# Get Selected Cell Values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, devexpress

I have created a calendar using a GridView in C# Winforms. I'm trying to get the values of all selected cells.

[image]

On a simple button click, Output should be :
**2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 18, 21, 26, 29**

I am having a hard time finding a way to get the dates/value of all selected cells. Any idea is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I encountered errors when I tried using both Fabio's and H.Fadlallah's codes. Might be because of the DevEx Components I was using. Though they did help me create the code I am using now.

Anyway, shown below is the code I used to that somehow gives me what I need.

```
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder xTokens = new StringBuilder();
        GridCell[] xCell = xgvCalendar.GetSelectedCells();

        for (int i = 0; i < xCell.Count(); i++)
        {
            int xRow = xCell[i].RowHandle;
            xTokens.Append(dtpTransDate.Value.ToString("MMMM") + " " + xgvCalendar.GetRowCellValue(xRow, xCell[i].Column.ToString()).ToString() + ", " + dtpTransDate.Value.ToString("yyyy"));
            if (i != xCell.Count()-1) xTokens.Append(" - ");
        }

        MessageBox.Show(xTokens.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
            private void selectedCellsButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                Int32 selectedCellCount =
                    dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
                if (selectedCellCount > 0)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.AreAllCellsSelected(true))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("All cells are selected", "Selected Cells");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Text.StringBuilder sb =
                            new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                        for (int i = 0;
                            i < selectedCellCount; i++)
                        {
                            sb.Append(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].Value.ToString()) ;


                      MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Selected Cells");

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DataGridView.SelectedCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells(v=vs.110).aspx) property and LINQ extension method [Enumerable.Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var values = gridView.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(cell => cell.Value);
string output = string.Join(", ", selectedValues);
```

`values` will be of type `IEnumerable<object>`, because `DataGridViewCell.Value` return `object` type.

`string.Join` will use `StringBuilder` and will call `.ToString()` for every item in the collection.